# C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\index.php on line 71 "> Edit

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Estoy haciendo un Php Crud pero otra una manera diferente.
Quiero incluir un botón de editar una fila y borrarla pero me sale el siguiente error.

C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\index.php on line 71 > Edit

C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\index.php on line 74 > Delete

Dejo el codigo del index.php ya que es el indica que tiene el error, los demas lo copie tal cual en el video.

```
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Masters</th>
                        <th>Class</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM personas";
                    $result_personas = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                    
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_personas)) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row['Name'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['description'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['date'] ?></td>
                            <td>

                            <!--Aqui se encuentra el error--->
                                <a href="edit.php? id=<?php echo $row['id']?>">
                                Edit
                                </a>
                                <a href="delete_task.php? id=<?php echo $row['id']?>">
                                Delete
                                </a>      
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?> 
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: El código así como está no produce errores. El único problema es que están separados la dirección con su variable get: `...href="edit.php? id=..."`, debe ser pegado `...href="edit.php?id=..."` para que el url se forme correctamente. Lo mismo pasa en el link de borrar.

Comment: Incluso con eso, me sigue saliendo el mismo errror